# Linux autostart

Tags: linux, bash, shell, autostart

I am preparing for exams and have different environments for different subjects. I want to be able to start for example a java_course script which opens the PDF's I need, and starts eclipse and firefox, and maybe another shell this will be independet from the shell I started.

So far I am starting with:

```
abc@xyz:~$ okular abc.pdf def.pdf hij.pdf & firefox & eclipse &
```

Everything which has been started from the shell will be closed as well.

Thanks in advance for any advices.

Comment: "Everything which has been started from the shell will be closed as well." - What do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

If applications you are launching from the shell are closing when you close the shell then they aren't detaching themselves the way they should be.

Those applications should be doing that correctly though I would think.

If they (or some other applications) aren't you can try redirecting standard input, output and error to/from `/dev/null` to help them with this:

```
$ { okular abc.pdf def.pdf hij.pdf & firefox & eclipse & } </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Alternatively, and perhaps more robustly, this is what tools like `nohup` and `detach` are for:

```
$ nohup okular abc.pdf def.pdf hij.pdf & nohup firefox & nohup eclipse &
```